# Making a prediction with a pastas timeseries model

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

For my thesis project I am trying to forecast groundwater levels by applying a particle filter which uses weather forecast data (specifically mm of rainfall and evaporation). As part of the particle filtering process I need to make a prediction of the groundwater level based on this weather forecast data, which I want to do using a Pastas model.

At the moment I have trained a Pastas model as follows:

```py
import pastas as ps

# set up model
model = ps.Model(gwml_train.gws)

# add stresses information
rain = ps.StressModel(wm_train.RH, ps.Gamma, name='rain', settings="prec")
evap = ps.StressModel(wm_train.EV, ps.Gamma, name='evap', settings="evap")
model.add_stressmodel(rain)
model.add_stressmodel(evap)

# solve model
model.solve()
```

Where the `gwml_train` is the groundwater level data for the period of 1-1-2018 until 1-1-2019 and `wm_train` the weather measurements for the same data. Rh is rainfall and EV is evaporation.

This model explains the groundwater level measurements that are given in combination with the weather measurements. What I want to do, is to make a prediction for a period in which no groundwater level measurements are given but there are weather measurements.

Specifically, I use a for-loop which makes a 30 day forecast for each day in the period 1-1-2019 until 1-3-2019.  At each day I get a dataset with the 30-day weather forecast for that day. What I would like to do, is to add this weather forecast data to the model and use it to predict the groundwater levels for that 30-day period. Is there a way to do this?

Adding the data to `solve()` does not work and the method `simulate()` does not take any data.

*This question was sent to me by a user via mail. I'm posting it here to add a pastas question on SO.*

*EDIT: updated question with user explanation.*

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have created a pastas Model `ml` with precipitation and evaporation as stresses. Optimizing the timeseries model on a specific period is done by specifying the period in `ml.solve()`:

```py
ml.solve(tmin="2010", tmax="2020")
```

To simulate a specific period use the same tmin/tmax options in `ml.simulate()`. So for a prediction of the groundwater level in january 2020:

```py
sim  = ml.simulate(tmin="2020-01-01", tmax="2020-01-31")
```

`sim` is a `pandas.Series` containing the simulated groundwater head. Note that the precipitation and evaporation timeseries do need to have data for the period you want to simulate, otherwise the model will use the mean of the timeseries to calculate the groundwater level.